# jQuery preventing form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### My html

```
<p><select name="status" class="form-control" id="showThisItem">
    <option value="">
        Select Status
    </option>
    <option value="Paid">
        Paid
    </option>
    <option value="Unpaid">
        Unpaid
    </option>
</select></p>

<td id="showHide">
    <label>Due Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="due_date" class="form-control" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="datepicker" required="true"> 
</td>
```

### My jquery code

```
$('#showHide').hide(500);
var showThis = $('#showThisItem');
var select = this.value;
showThis.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Unpaid') {
        $('#showHide').show(500);
    }
    else {
        $('#showHide').hide(500);
    }
});
```

I used this code to display a `td` element. When I select `Paid` the `td` is hidden and when I select `Unpaid` the `td` is displayed. It is hidden on page load.

However, if I select `Unpaid` then I can submit the form and if I select `paid` the submit button does not work.

Comment: `"if i select Paid the submit button does not work"` - In what way does it "not work"?  Is it not submitting the form at all?  What's stopping it?  (Note: We don't see the form, or the submit button, or any code attached to either of them.)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. but I think what you want to do is remove the "required" from the due_date field then you should be able to submit. (you should post this in a snippet or jsfiddle in order to solicit better responses

Comment: When you select unpaid, do you also enter a date into the date picker?

Comment: The code snippet(s) that you provide are supposed to be there to help us. The snippets you provide are minimal, and not enough to see the entirety of the issue.
Create a working jsfiddle.net displaying your issue.

Comment: @happymacarts Thank you. Your suggestion works perfectly.

Comment: I removed (Solved) from the title. Accepting an answer is enough to mark it as "solved". No further action is required on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is listed as `required`:

```
<input type="text" name="due_date" class="form-control" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="datepicker" required="true">
```

This will cause the form to be invalid and not allow it to submit. If it is only required when **Unpaid** is selected then I would look into setting that attribute dynamically with jQuery when **Unpaid** is selected.

Something like

```
<script>
 $('#showHide').hide(500);
  var showThis = $('#showThisItem');
  var select = this.value;
  showThis.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Unpaid') {
        $('#showHide').show(500).find('input').prop('required',true);
    }
    else {
      $('#showHide').hide(500).find('input').prop('required',false);;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you  for solving my question. I will marked as a solved ASAP.

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry @LoganRx I posted a similar solution (you just beat me to it)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `due_date` input has the `required` attribute.

While changing the visibility, you should toggle that too:

```
showThis.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Unpaid') {
        $('#showHide').show(500);
        $('#showHide :input').prop('required', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#showHide').hide(500);
        $('#showHide :input').prop('required', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is what you are looking for , but thought it may help. Next time try to more clearly ask your question

I was not sure if you needed to maintain the required on the date field or if you only want that required IF they mark it paid

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#showHide').hide();
  //event binding should be in a document ready 
  //to make sure that the binding is done after the elements exist

  $('#showThisItem').change(function(e) {
    //bind a change event to the select element
    console.log('VALUE: ' + $(this).val())
    if ($(this).val() == 'Unpaid') {
      $('#datepicker').prop("disabled", true);
      
      $('#showHide').hide(500);
    } else {
      $('#datepicker').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#showHide').show(500);
    }

  });

  $('.submit').click(function(){
    var data = $('#paidForm').serialize();
    console.log(data);
  });
  




});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="paidForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="status" class="form-control" id="showThisItem">
          <option value="">
            Select Status
          </option>
          <option value="Paid">
            Paid
          </option>
          <option value="Unpaid">
            Unpaid
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="showHide">
        <label>Due Date</label>
        <input type="Date" name="due_date" class="form-control" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="datepicker" required='required' disabled='disabled'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```